# Unwanted text appearing on wordpress site

Tags: php, html, wordpress, overflow

I have inherited a WordPress site with the word 'test' appearing in the very bottom corner of each page. I can't find it anywhere within the php admin panel, e.g. themes, widgets, pages, stylesheets etc.

I couldn't see a solution here:
[text is appearing at the top left of my wordpress site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34715400/text-is-appearing-at-the-top-left-of-my-wordpress-site)
or anywhere else on the forum.

When I inspect the code it appears within the body of the code but outside any div paragraphs. Is there a simple way to find it and remove it?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8rTq.jpg)

Many thanks in advance for any help.
Andy.

Comment: you can search the text in the whole file and remove

Comment: Hi Vivek, thanks for answering. there isn't one single whole file, there are hundreds of them. i've tried searching through them but lots of them contain the word 'test'. i'm hoping there's an easier solution incase this happens again in the future.

Comment: Try viewing the source code with `Ctrl+u` instead because it will show you precisely how the HTML is being generated by WordPress. The developer console "cleans" things up and displays to you how it interprets your HTML code even if it is malformed.

Comment: Also, if someone wanted to play a trick on you then you would have a hard time finding something like `echo base64_decode('dGVzdA==');` or `echo 't'.'e'.'s'.'t';`

Comment: Try viewing your site with JavaScript disabled, it could be getting dynamically added by JS.

Comment: Thanks MZ, displaying the source code just showed the same thing except with all the div code showing instead of hidden. the word 'test' was in exactly the same place. i searched all the javascript code which contains the word 'test' (using agent ransack) but none of it had the line i'm looking for. i'm beginning to think i'll have to install apache and load the website locally in order to find it.

Answer (score 0):

check the  function.php  of your theme, if not found this text  use this plugin:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/string-locator/

with this plugin you can check the location of  it, then remove the text.

Comment: Thanks themich. the function.php file was a custom one built by the previous dev (devname-function.php). the word 'test' wasn't in there, but you got me thinking it's something to do with the theme. the string locator couldn't find anything so i checked in Genesis > Theme Settings. i was sure i'd checked everywhere before but obviously not because voila it was down at the bottom in the wp_footer() section. so i guess whatever text you put in there is generated dynamically each time, without ever being added to the code. thanks for your help, and thanks everyone who replied.